# Read QR Code from scanned PDF

Tags: java, pdf, qr-code, bfo

I'm trying to insert and read qrcode's from PDF files. To create/read qr codes from images i'm using [zxing project](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) and to manipulate the pdf i'm using [Big Faceless PDF](http://bfo.com/products/pdf/).

Everything works well if i create the QR Code, insert into my pdf, and then read the images from the pdf and convert the correct one to QR Code. **However**, if i try to to read images from a scanned document (with a qr code sticker attach to it), i cannot obtain the qr code image from the pdf (the only image i can get, using Big Faceless PDF, is the document it self).

Does anyone knows a Java library to search in pdf files for qr codes?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only reliable way to do this is to convert the PDF page to a bitmap, then using something like zxing to scan the entire page for the barcode. Extracting the individual images that make up the page won't work on every document: the barcode may be created using graphics operations rather than as an embedded image (that's how we do it), or if you PDF was scanned from a paper source as you've described, it will usually be one big image.

Once you've got the PDF converted to a bitmap, ZXing should be able to do this, at least in theory. Naturally I'd recommend sticking with us for the conversion to bitmap ;-)

If ZXing is having trouble finding the code, make sure it has enough white-space around it - you need 4 clear modules on all sides, so for smaller codes it should be about 10% of the width of the code in whitespace around the code, to help it scan.

Cheers... Mike (CTO@BFO)

Comment: Hi mike. I actually used ICEPdf to convert the PDF page into a BufferedImage. I tried to use BFO, but you're documentation was a bit abstract over that subject. Do you want to give an example? :)

Comment: `PDF pdf = new PDF(new PDFReader(new File("in.pdf")));
PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(pdf);
PagePainter painter = parser.getPagePainter(pagenumber);
BufferedImage image = painter.getBufferedImage(dpi, PDFParser.RGBA);`

Not much to it! Email us at support if you need more info.

Comment: is there something similar for IOS?

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this to work:

1. Use `Imagick` to converts pdfs into pngs
2. Use `Zxing` \ `QrReader` to read the QR data